# Отладчик в Android Studio.

Tags: отладка, android, android-studio

Всем привет.

Есть некое приложение, исходников которого я не имею. Есть планшет с root/bb, включённой отладкой и этим приложением. Можно ли как-то натравить дебаггер Android Studio на это приложение, чтобы я мог видеть названия выполняемых в приложении методов? Сначала я подключил планшет к ПК в режиме отладки, но нужного приложения в списке не было. Я расковырял его, впихнул в манифест `android:debuggable="true"` и снова собрал. Приложение в списке появилось, в Android Studio начал работать Memory Monitor, а вот штуки для просмотра выполняемых методов я не нашёл.

Вот пример того, что я ожидаю увидеть:

```
01.01.1970 10:00:00 - com.test.app - MainActivity.class - onCreate
01.01.1970 10:00:01 - com.test.app - MainActivity.class - initialize
01.01.1970 10:00:10 - com.test.app - MainActivity.class - getInfo
01.01.1970 10:00:13 - com.test.app - InfoGetter.class - doInBackground
01.01.1970 10:00:29 - com.test.app - InfoGetter.class - onPostExecute
01.01.1970 10:00:30 - com.test.app - MainActivity.class - hackPentagon
```

Пожалуйста, помогите найти эту функцию в отладчике, если таковая вообще существует. Как правильно загуглить - не знаю, т.к. даже не имею понятия, как правильно истолковать мой запрос :)

P.S. Если всё пройдёт удачно, то через некоторое время сделаю отчётик, зачем мне это надо было.

Comment: http://www.decompileandroid.com/

Comment: @SuperCreeper, если "проблема решена", то не соизволите ли написать, как именно она решена? А то вдруг это еще кому-нибудь понадобится...

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужны исходники приложения. 
Но исходники достать можно. Как? - В каждом АПК файле лежит DEX файл (Dalvik EXecutable), в котором собраны все .class файлы приложения, которые совершенно просто декомпилируются в .java файлы. Dex в набор классов можно преобразовать при помощи утилиты Dex2Jar (гугл знает, где взять. Я не помню к сожалению). .class в .java преобразовать можно при помощи любого java декомпилятора, например JAD (он старенький, не поддерживает анотации, а так - работает).

Следующая проблема - с большой долей вероятности приложение обфусцировано(Proguard например). Если это так, то там разобраться будет очень сложно (читай невозможно).

Comment: @metalurgus, разбирал приложение ещё на самом планшете в ApkTool. К моему удивлению, код оказался необфусцирован, но очень сильно попорчен (лютый говнокод). Поэтому мне было бы легче просто посмотреть где, когда и какие методы выполняются.